# как очистить объект js в том числе и вложенный в цикле?

Tags: javascript

Как всем свойствам присвоить значение 0?

```
data: {
  one:{
    x: 10,
    y:20
  },
  two:{
    x: 10,
    y:20
  },
  three:{
    object1:{
      x: 10,
      y:20
    },
    object2:{
      x: 10,
      y:20
    },
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать рекурсивно:

```js
const object = {
  data: {
    one:{
      x: 10,
      y: 20
    },
    two:{
      x: 10,
      y: 20
    },
    three:{
      object1:{
        x: 10,
        y: 20
      },
      object2:{
        x: 10,
        y: 20
      },

    }
  }
};

reset(object);

console.log(JSON.stringify(object, null, '  '));

function reset(obj) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) reset(value);
    else obj[key] = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В случае таких вот простых значений с заранее известной схемой (в данном случае `{ x: Number, y: Number }`), можно использовать обычную строковую замену на сериализованном представлении объекта:

```js
const foo = {
  data: {
    one: { x: 10, y: 20 },
    two: { x: 10, y: 20 },
    three: {
      object1: { x: 10, y: 20 },
      object2: { x: 10, y: 20 },
    },
  },
};

const reset = obj => JSON.parse(
  JSON.stringify(foo).replace(/{\s*"[xy]":[^}]+}/g, '{ "x": 0, "y": 0 }')
);
console.log(reset(foo));
```

Этот подход должен работать быстрее прочих, но весьма опасен: его **не следует использовать** в случаях когда схема вложенных объектов может варьироваться (ошибочно совпадая с указанным шаблоном замены).

Comment: Тут замена имеет предельно простую логику: если встречается объект первое свойство которого имеет имя `x` или `y` - этот объект заменяется на "обнуленный". Регистрозависимость выражения предполагается (флаг `i` не нужен), т.к. и имена объектных свойств в JS регистрозависимы.